# ociexecute(): ORA-00907: Missing Right Parentheses

Tags: php, sql

I have all my parentheses though.. Any other reason I could be getting this error? Here is my php code. I obviously removed my password for this so that is not the reason.

```
 <?php

 modDatabase();

 function modDatabase() {

   ini_set('display_errors','On');
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $db_host = "";
   $db_user = "";
   $db_pass = "";
   $con = oci_connect($db_user, $db_pass, $db_host);
   // Check connection
   if (!$con){
      $e = oci_error;
        print "<br> connection failed:";
        print htmlentities($e['message']);
        exit;
  }

  $today = date("H:i:s");
  $one="1";
  $sql="call createRepairJob('$_POST[contract]', '$_POST[rId]', '$_POST[cust]' , '$_POST[product]' , $today , $one , '$_POST[employee]' , '$_POST[prob]' , '$_POST[model]')";
  $sqlParse = OCIParse($con, $sql);
  $result = OCIExecute($sqlParse);

  if (!$result){
    echo "invalid";
    exit;
  }
  echo "success";
  OCILogoff($con);

}


?>
```

Comment: I think your POST variables should be like this: `$_POST['contract']` and not like this: `$_POST[contract]`. Same for all the variables.

Comment: Type "SQL injection" into google and start reading...

Comment: @Maximus not in an interpolated string, no

Comment: Could you try and echo your $sql string to see what the actual SQL query is? Do this on the dev environment obviously :)